# c++ start sound clip at an offset

Tags: c++, audio

I want to play a mp3 starting a couple of minutes or hours into the song, instead of the begging. The code im using is very simple.

```
mciSendString((L"play " + path).c_str(), NULL, 0, NULL);
```

Is there away to do this using mciSendString?

Comment: Have you tried any of the flags listed here? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743667%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can start a sound at a time by doing.

```
mciSendString((L"play " + path + L" from 1000").c_str(), NULL, 0, NULL);
```

this will start the sound 1 second into the song.

link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743667%28v=vs.85%29.aspx